# Angular dynamic pages with routing

Tags: angularjs

What I am trying to do is create a dynamic list of speakers for an event and the individual profile pages for each speaker. I've already created the list using `ng-repeat` and the links are working using `ng-href`. Using angular routing I've even got the page template loading, the only piece missing for this is figuring out how to populate the page template with the data specific to the selected speaker. To clarify, there is a dynamic list made with an unknown number of speakers, each will have a profile page using the same template, however what I am struggling to do is populate that template with the details for the individual speaker. There are similar questions on here, though they appear to be trying to create dynamic templates rather than dynamic content, and don't resolve the question as it exists. Here is some of the existing code:

```
// The routing:

.when('/profile/:name*', {
     templateUrl : 'pages/profile.html',
     controller  : 'profileController'
 })

// The lists and links on the index page...

<div class="grid" ng-repeat="speaker in home.speakers">
   <a ng-href="profile/{{speaker.url}}">
      <div>....</div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the [manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) - At the bottom of the page you'll have a great exampel on hot to implemente this

Comment: @AlonEitan you're right, I haven't even seen this before. I'll investigate it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Route

in your routes you should have something like

```
.state('Prof', {
     url: '/Prof',
     templateUrl: 'rout/to/yout/template.html'
})
```

## Service/Factory

Create a factory to get the data from your rest api with a http call, something like this.

```
.factory('profContent', function($http){
  return {
    getContent: function(profid){
        return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/prof', { params: { user_id: profid });
    }
  };
});
```

## Controller

```
.controller('profCtrl', ['$scope', 'profContent', function($scope, profContent){

  profContent.getContent(profid).then(function(response){
    $scope.firstName = response.data.fName;
    $scope.lastName = response.data.lName;
  });
}]);
```

use the controller to set the `$scope` for the view with the things you got from your service.

## Conclusion

You can pass a param that you bind to the scope and use this to query the DB and get the correct data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is certainly different than i thought it would be. I've currently been creating a list using ajax to create JSON data. Is there a way of continuing that instead of using the factory? I thought i had that in the question but i might of deleted it

Comment: not so sure about ajax, don't think you really need it in angular. in Angular the data flow example could be `mongodb > express route > factory > controller > view`. this is generally the accepted way of geting and posting data since angular is single page it shouldn't require ajax.

Comment: sorry let me correct myself, after a quick google search i found that a service/factory http call is an ajax call [here is a link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_ajax.htm)

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually using mysql as a db, getting the data with ajax, turning it into JSON. So though it is dynamic in the sense that content can be added and removed on the server side, the JSON file will be the source. I just need to be able to take all the info from JSON for a specific individual to populate a page. You can go to http://codesty.xyz/masculine to see the live example. The grid there is the list of speakers, which right now has dummy data, clicking on one of those will go to let's say speakers/john_doe in example. I just need to populate that page with just John Doe's info

Comment: So i guess i can skip the services for the ajax as I've done that before, what I'm really struggling with is taking one individual from the JSON and populating a page with it. It's fine for now if it works off a hand coded JSON file even, just to get the functionality there, I can handle the ajax aspect myself I think.

Comment: you would use the service to get a specific speakers data via your api. but if you have all the json data there and you go to a speaker page you just need to take the speakers id from the url and pass that to the service/factory you use on the json. still use a factory to keep concerns separated since you have to get specific data from your json data.

Comment: That's what I think I'd want to do, something like `speakers/name` where I pull the name from the url and then populate the template with the data. Would you have resources to reference me to for this? And would using html5 mode change how I do this?